# Tensorflow objects not displaying

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just installed TensorFlow using `conda install tensorflow`from the anaconda prompt. I'm using Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

I thought I'd try it out with something simple, like

```
rnd_ints = tf.random_normal([10], dtype=tf.float64)
```

When I call `rnd_ints` all I get is this:

```
<tf.Tensor 'random_normal:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float64>
```

I thought I was supposed to be getting an array object of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor):

> A Tensor is a symbolic handle to one of the outputs of an Operation.
>   It does not hold the values of that operation's output, but instead
>   provides a means of computing those values in a TensorFlow tf.Session.
>
> This class has two primary purposes:
>
> A Tensor can be passed as an input to another Operation. This builds a
>   dataflow connection between operations, which enables TensorFlow to
>   execute an entire Graph that represents a large, multi-step
>   computation.
>
> After the graph has been launched in a session, the value of the
>   Tensor can be computed by passing it to tf.Session.run. t.eval() is a
>   shortcut for calling tf.get_default_session().run(t).

The answer to your question: when you call `tf.random_normal()` you create a `Tensor` object, which does not have actual values stored. In order to get an output you'll need to run it inside a **session**. Here's how you can get an actual output:

```
import tensorflow as tf
rnd_ints = tf.random_normal([10], dtype=tf.float64)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    rnd = sess.run(rnd_ints)
print(rnd)
# [-1.59628093  0.62648824  0.18566968  0.2274149   1.27171951 -0.18103614
#  -2.05964716  0.37477217  0.3355942  -1.57350681]
```